# change search entite store message magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

i tried to change the default seacrh message of the Search Box i managed to do it with the help of Forums now i am facing an issue with it search box is displaying the current page name instead of the message given on the text box

any guesses...

regards

Comment: If you want a real answer to this question, you'll need to post more detail in the question. What modifications did you make? What does it display now? Give specific examples, and as much code as may be relevant. Looking forward to seeing your changes!

Answer (score 1):

Undo your previous changes and use [Inline translation](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/) instead.

Comment: i enabled the display inline YES for front-end and then replaced the text for the search.Although the text got changed but this Issue arised after that I also tried to manage it thru the bd for translate inline table but no success

Answer (score 0):

please have a look

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/17514/